# Can't get Eclipse to work on Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

So, I installed Ubuntu on my laptop yesterday. It is the first time I have used a Linux distro. Most of it is making sense. Unfortunately,I can't get Eclipse to work. I installed it from the terminal when I was prompted, and everything seems to go fine - Eclipse launches, it looks normal to me - but when I open my saved java files from Dropbox, they are filled with errors. Eclipse on OS opens and runs these files without a problem, but Eclipse on Ubuntu says they are all wrong. I am taking an introductory programming class so I am in the midst of a steep learning curve for all of this. Error messages are below. Thanks!!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Beaufort : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: Beaufort. Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the Java classes were compiled with a different JDK version than what you're using to run them.

Try to install JDK 1.5 and then in the Eclipse project settings, change to use that version.

Comment: Okay, I  installed 1.5 and then I went to Project>Properties>Java compiler>Configure workspace settings and I selected 1.5. Eclipse then rebuilt the project but it did not fix the problem. Maybe I was supposed to select 1.5 someplace else?

Comment: The files were originally compiled using eclipse on Windows. I had no problem  opening them an running them  on my mac. Do I need to set a path variable?